# Could not create task ':app:createDebugVariantModel'

Tags: android, flutter

been searching about this error for the past hour and I couldn't find anything here or on google

gradle version tried 7.4 and 4.5
flutter version 3.16

tried:

- `flutter clean` then rebuild
- deleting the gradle cache and rebuild
- sync using android studio
- changing the gradle version

error message I'm getting

```
* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: A build operation failed.
    Could not create task ':app:createDebugVariantModel'.
Could not create task ':app:createDebugVariantModel'.
Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because "value" is null
```

Comment: Did it resolve for you?

Comment: @user1875926 I basically build a whole new app and moved my flutter code there...

Comment: Okay, but all the libs and config would still remain same, no

Comment: @user1875926 mostly they're the same, yes

Comment: I believe my issue was in the Android part of the code